# ERROR TypeError: _RNGestureHandlerModule.default.flushOperations is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes

Tags: android, react-native, expo, mobile-application, chrome-app-developer-tool

I create the React Native Expo Mobile app. I got this error in android ERROR TypeError: _RNGestureHandlerModule.default.flushOperations is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes.But,Not in IOS .how solve this error in android

Need Correct Answer. I am working On expo 50

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. It got fixed when I install `react-native-gesture-handler` as recommended by Pratik Prakash.

```
npx expo install react-native-gesture-handler
```

Answer (score 3):

As previous answers suggest installing `react-native-gesture-handler` resolves the issue.

But in the codebase `react-native-gesture-handler` is not used anywhere, I don't get it, what is the purpose of installing the library that you don't use. Does it have something to do with `expo`?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to install react-native-gesture-handler with

```
npx expo install react-native-gesture-handler
```

but I am still getting this error as well:
ERROR  TypeError: _RNGestureHandlerModule.default.flushOperations is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes

I have been importing it like so

```
import { GestureHandlerRootView} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```

I am also only experiencing this issue on Android, but not on iOS

Answer (score 2):

For me was different version of this package installed on the project, so be aware in case you getting such error you probably will also get this warnings in logs:
[image: error when is installed different version of react-native-gesture-handler]

Next solution is to check if you have this package installed. A good advice for me was to follow instructions presented in errors, 90% responses is there.

Answer (score 2):

Update the dependencies in your project.  this way,

for npm,

```
npm install @react-navigation/native@latest
npm install react-native-gesture-handler@latest
npm install react-native-reanimated@latest
```

for yarn,

```
yarn add @react-navigation/native@latest
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler@latest
yarn add react-native-reanimated@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

- In Expo go everything is working amazing, but development build crashing : https://forums.expo.dev/t/in-expo-go-everything-is-working-amazing-but-development-build-crashing/74480
- Troubleshooting : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/troubleshooting/
- Problem with the version of react-native-gesture-handler that you have installed. The error message indicates that the flushOperations method is undefined, which suggests that the method is not being exposed properly by the library.

  ```
  npx expo install react-native-gesture-handler
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I had old codebase which I wanted to update with the latest versions.
I was able to mitigate the issue following the below expo documentation.
https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/gestures/#install-and-configure-libraries

Answer (score 1):

```js
npx expo install react-native-gesture-handler
```

works for me ass well,
don`t forget to stop the server and run again,
if it still show problem try clear the expo cache:

```js
npx expo start --clear
```